# Avoiding `fgets()` double Enter hits

Tags: c, fgets

I am trying to collect data from user and I want to accomplish the task using `fgets()`.

In my `main.c` file:

```
do
    {
        user = ask_user_info();

        // ... Code exporting data to file ...

        free(user);

        fprintf(stdout, "Do you want to add another user?\nChoice: ");
        scanf("%c[^\n]", &choice);

    } while (choice == 'y');
```

Here are the functions I have written to get the job done:

```
UserData *ask_user_info()
{
    char firstname[STRLEN];
    char lastname[STRLEN];
    char username[STRLEN];
    char password[STRLEN];
    char email[STRLEN];

    fprintf(stdout, "First Name: ");
    get_user_input(firstname);
    flush_stdin();

    fprintf(stdout, "Last Name: ");
    get_user_input(lastname);
    flush_stdin();

    fprintf(stdout, "Username: ");
    get_user_input(username);
    flush_stdin();

    fprintf(stdout, "Password: ");
    get_user_input(password);
    flush_stdin();

    fprintf(stdout, "Email: ");
    get_user_input(email);
    flush_stdin();

    return fill_fields(firstname, lastname, username, password, email);
}

void get_user_input(char *input)
{
    int length;
    char *buffer = (char *) malloc (STRLEN * sizeof(char));
    (*buffer) = '\0';

    if (fgets(buffer, STRLEN, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        length = strlen(buffer)-1;
        buffer[length] = '\0';
        strncpy(input, buffer, length+1);
    }

    free(buffer);
}

UserData *fill_fields(const char firstname[], const char lastname[], 
                        const char username[], const char password[], const char email[])
{
    UserData *user = (UserData *) malloc (sizeof(UserData));

    user->firstname = (char *) malloc (strlen(firstname) * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(user->firstname, firstname, strlen(firstname));
    user->lastname = (char *) malloc (strlen(lastname) * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(user->lastname, lastname, strlen(lastname));
    user->username = (char *) malloc (strlen(username) * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(user->username, username, strlen(username));
    user->password = (char *) malloc (strlen(password) * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(user->password, password, strlen(password));
    user->email = (char *) malloc (strlen(email) * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(user->email, email, strlen(email));

    return user;
}

void flush_stdin()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

Everything compiles and everything seems to work properly, but when the program asks for user input, (most of the times) it requires the user to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice to move on to the next input.

On one hand I know that this behaviour is caused by the `flush_stdin()` function. On the other I can't get rid of the `flush_stdin()` function because it makes sure that no input field gets skipped. If I did the program would output something like `First Name: Last Name:`

How do I avoid the double hit and make sure all input is collected?

Comment: I think all those `malloc()` calls are unnecessary.  Simply read into the buffers, passing their length along with their pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with double-enter comes from combinations of calls that looks like this:

```
get_user_input(some_field);
flush_stdin();
```

- The first line of code requires the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in order to indicate to `fgets` that he has finished typing the response.
- The second line of code requires the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in order to end the `while` loop inside `flush_stdin`

To fix this problem you should remove calls to `flush_stdin`, and modify `get_user_input` to skip over empty lines:

```
void get_user_input(char *input) {
    int length;
    *input = '\0';
    do {
        if (fgets(buffer, STRLEN, stdin) == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        length = strlen(buffer)-1;
        buffer[length] = '\0';
    } while (length == 0);
}
```

The `do`/`while` loop will skip over unexpected `'\n'` in the input as it takes new data from the user, without you having to flush the input explicitly.

Note that you can remove `malloc`/`free`, along with string copying, from your `get_user_input`, because the caller already provides a sufficient buffer. Your code assumes that the buffer is at least `STRLEN` long, but it may be better to pass the length explicitly as a second parameter to the function.

Answer (score 2):

The real trick is to not mix usage of `fgets()` with `scanf()` and related functions.   The reason is that they handle the presence of newline characters differently.   `fgets()` reads it in if the buffer is long enough to hold a complete line.  `scanf()`, depending on choice of format string, stops at the newline character and leaves it in the stream - where it will cause the next call of `fgets()` to return immediately.

Try using `fgets()` to handle *all* of the reading from the user.   You can use `sscanf()` to interpret the string that the user inputs if needed.

One benefit of that is that you won't actually need the `flush_stdin()` function, because there won't be spurious cases of a newline sometimes needing to be discarded, and sometimes not.