# fgets wants input twice

Tags: c, input

I'm still quite new to C and do have problems with how to indent code, so I apologise for this in advance. I am trying to get the programme to input strings and output readability score. I have the code all written out, however, whenever input a phase and press enter the programme doesn't execute the rest of the code, instead I have to input something else before moving on. I have no idea why! Please could someone help?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
 
 
 
 
int main(void)
{
    char str[500]; // think of this like an array
    int alphabet =0 , i =0, word=0, special_characters =0, vowels = 0;
   
   
       printf("Input the string:\n");
       fgets(str,500,stdin);   // <== issue here where I  have to input string twice for while loop to occur!
       
 
 
     /* Checks each character of string*/
   
    while(str[i] !='\0')// while there is a character and not empty space
    {
       
   
   
        if(str[i] ==  'a' || str[i] == 'e' || str[i] == 'i' ||
            str[i] == 'o' || str[i] == 'u' || str[i] == 'A' ||
            str[i] == 'E' || str[i] == 'I' || str[i] == 'O' ||
            str[i] == 'U')
        {
            ++vowels;
           
        }
     
        else if((str[i] ==' ' || str[i]=='\n' || str[i]=='\t'))
        { // if there is not space, tab or enter, then logically there is a word
            word++; // after not finding a space it is told to look for next one
        }
        else if((str[i] =='?' || str[i]=='!' || str[i]=='.')) // looks for sentance enders
        {
            special_characters++; // keeps going until text ends
        }
        else if((str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z') || (str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z'))
        {
        // only  i is just a counter of each letter in
        // this case. alphabet is told to increase
 
            alphabet++; // made this a loop that goes onto next letter
           
 
        }
 
     
         i++; //  tells i to scan over ALL if loops by being INSDIE the while loop but not
         // part of the IF statements!
         
    }    
   
        //L = Letters ÷ Words × 100 = 639 ÷ 119 × 100 ? 537
 
        //S = Sentences ÷ Words × 100 = 5 ÷ 119 × 100 ? 4.20
                   
        double letters = vowels + alphabet;
        double w = word;
        double d = 100.0;
        double L = (letters/w)*d;
        double e = special_characters;  // sentances
        double S= (e/w)*100;
        scanf("%lf",&S);
        double index = (0.0588 * L) -(0.296 * S)- 15.8;
        scanf("%lf",&index);
        double round(double index);
                 
 
 
       
        if(index <=1)
        {
            printf("Below Grade 1\n");
        }
        else if(index >=3 && index <4)
        {
            printf(" Grade 3\n");
           
        }
        else if(index >=5 && index <6)
        {
            printf(" Grade 5\n");
           
        }
        else if(index >=7 && index <8)
        {
            printf(" Grade 7\n");
           
        }
        else if(index >=8 && index <9)
        {
            printf(" Grade 8\n");
           
        }
        else if(index >=9 && index <10)
        {
            printf(" Grade 9\n");
           
        }
        else if(index >=10 && index <11)
        {
            printf(" Grade 9\n");
           
        }
        else if(index >=16)
        {
            printf(" Grade 16+\n");
           
        }
       
 
 
 
}
```

Comment: I think this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286010/avoiding-fgets-double-enter-hits

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely further down on the `scanf()`

Try

```
        // ...
        double S= (e/w)*100;
        printf("Enter value for S:\n");   // suggestion for feedback
        if (scanf("%lf", &S) != 1) {
            //scanf failed
            fprintf(stderr, "scanf failed.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //...
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! Why would this cause an issue?

Comment: There really is no issue with `fgets()`, but because your program has no output between entering the input and asking for the S, it appears to you it has stopped... in fact it has executed all statements and is happily waiting for S. The suggestion of printing a prompt just provides feedback to the user.

Comment: Exactly, @sirneil just put a print statement after the while loop and execute your code by giving the input normally, you will understand.